# Image to base64 in xslt

Tags: xslt

I need to convert a image to base64binary content. Can we do it in xslt. I was able to convert string to base64 using saxon:string-to-base64Binary extension function. But how to convert image to base64. Can anyone help on this issue please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in function or Saxon extension function to do this. You would have to write your own extension function.